# Safety of multiple public keys per McEliece private key?

Tags: mceliece, misuse-resistant

I noticed that, when deriving a Classic McEliece public key from a private key, [randomness is required](https://github.com/PQClean/PQClean/blob/0cdedc78dc429ef3dd251257d9f2634e725d0536/crypto_kem/mceliece6960119f/clean/pk_gen.c#L158), and also that [this randomness is normally provided at once, during key *pair* generation](https://github.com/PQClean/PQClean/blob/0cdedc78dc429ef3dd251257d9f2634e725d0536/crypto_kem/mceliece6960119f/clean/operations.c#L148).

I'm guessing it's not usual to ever generate additional public keys "after the fact".

I'm further *guessing* that if you did so, and published more than 1 public key for the same private key, and decrypted messages encrypted with these various public keys, and reported KEM decapsulation failures back to the senders, you might compromise your key or your communications in some way.

What does the threat model for this (ab)use-case actually look like?

Comment: I'm not entirely sure that I'm following. I look at the code and I see a *random permutation* being mentioned, and no mention of a RNG. A random permutation is not the same thing as a random, e.g. the AES block cipher is a random permutation selected by the secret key, but it is fully deterministic.

Comment: The ClassicMcEliece specification also makes no mention of randomness used to generate the public key (apart from what is used to generate the private key)